# Does FFT magnitude spectrum graph consist of spectral lines or points

Tags: fft

Hi I am using zedgraph to plot an FFT of a signal using c#.The FFT spectrum gives coefficients vs the frequency bins.I am confused whether the plot should consist of spectral lines(ie verticle lines) corresponding to each frequency bins or data point values?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Data points ofcourse. Spectral lines is a visualization that is mostly used for optical frequencies, but it is analogous to a FFT spectrum. Replace the data point values in the FFT spectrum with color mapped lines indicating magnitude/intensity and you get spectral lines. It depends on what type of signal you want to study.

Comment: Thank you so much.I hope it will solve my problem.Thanks again.